# Is it possible that a previously imported module can still be 'remembered'?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have removed the `import webpage_get` but still have the line calling the module in my code, `source_code = webpage_get.wget(website)`

Unexpectedly, the module still runs despite it no longer being imported. 
PyCharm recognises that it hasn't been imported and highlights the module name as such.

How can a module that is no longer being imported still work?
Are the imported modules somehow saved? Is there a way to remove any 'saved' modules?

I have restarted PyCharm and my machine multiple times already.

```
website = r'https://www.w3schools.com/'

def main():
    source_code = webpage_get.wget(website)



def wget(url):
    try:
        webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        page_contents = webpage.read()
        webpage.close()
        page_contents = page_contents.decode()
        return page_contents
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'error loading webpage: {err}')
```

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: I've never experience that. Maybe PyCharm does some caching of imports? If you can verify, this might be worth a bug report.

Comment: That's going to depend on how you're running this code and the details of the particular import. We can't tell what's going on from what you've posted.

Comment: I have now added the relevant parts of my code

Comment: You've just defined a bunch of functions. You haven't actually called any of them. The code that needs the missing imports never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any stale *.pyc files in your project directory.

`pyc` files are built as part of the Python build process. Sometimes if you move or rename a module, a stale `module_name.pyc` will stick around and cause issues.